# C++ Looping and scanf validate alphabet, capital alphabet and numbers

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, scanf

I have some problem with my code, it appears after I compile and run the code it will output twice and also wrong output.

My task is to repeatedly input numbers/alphabet/capital and output the results accordingly. As for the while loop, I believe I have to put `while(1)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    int num;

    printf("\nEnter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) 
        printf("%c\nIt is an alphabet.", c);

    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
        printf("%c\n It is a capital alphabet.", c);

    if (c <= '1' ||c >= '1') 
        printf("\nIt is a numeric");

    else 
        printf("error");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: There should be an `else if` chain... and it isn't there...

Comment: `if (c <= '1' ||c >= '1')` is wrong. – Did you try to *debug* the code?

Comment: Please make sure you know exactly what language you are learning. Your code resembles C. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: You really shouldn't be writing comparisons like this wrt determining the category of a character.  You have `std::islower`, `std::isupper`, and `std::isdigit` that serves this purpose.  For example, if your system is EBCDIC, your comparison for lower case will fail.  Let the standard functions determine the character category -- it knows all of these details you may not be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three changes are needed.

First of all use `else if`

Secondly to test numeric use `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`.

And at last but not the least: use `getchar()` as the last statement of the loop to eat the `\n` character which is in the buffer and not taken by `scanf`

Comment: Ya right. @LogicStuff. Using ASCII value came to my mind before that.

Answer (score 1):

You need work like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char c;
int num, int general=0;

printf("\nEnter a character: ");
scanf("%c", &c);



if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) {
    printf("%c\nIt is an alphabet.", c);
    general++;
  }


if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')){
    printf("%c\n It is a capital alphabet.", c);
    general++;
  }

if (c <= '1' ||c >= '1') {
    printf("\nIt is a numeric");
    general++;
  }


if (general==0)
    printf("error");

 return 0;
}
```

or you can use in "catch and switch".